# Convert CamelCase xml/json to ruby named attributes with ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, activeresource, camelcasing

I'm using ActiveResource to consume a REST service.  The xml from the service looks like:

```
<Person>
  <FirstName>Kevin</FirstName>
  <LastName>Berridge</LastName>
</Person>
```

ActiveResource parses this just fine, but it uses the names verbatim.  So the model class will look like:

```
p = Person.find(1)
p.FirstName
p.LastName
```

I would much prefer if this would follow the Ruby naming conventions and look like:

```
p = Person.find(1)
p.first_name
p.last_name
```

Does ActiveResource have a way to do this?  Is there a way I can hook into ActiveResource and add this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a quick way to change the way ActiveResource names attributes, but you can implement `method_missing` to access the existing attributes with your preferred spellings:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  send name.to_s.classify.to_sym, *args, &block
end
```

Alternatively, you might be able to define alternately-named methods dynamically by iterating through `attributes.keys` and using `define_method`, though I'm not sure *when* in your object's life cycle you would do that (constructor?).